# Random access and update of an stl::set

Tags: c++, stl, set

I'm using a stl::set to keep elements sorted as they are inserted. My question is about the random access. If I have a complex class(difficult to init, for example), I found that is easy to insert, because I define the less operator into class. But if the key is the class itself, how do I need to access to the class? With a find()? I need to init a complex class only to find my class?

So my question is: how to random access to a set elements when elements are complex classes difficult to initialize?

Thanks

Comment: You might have to write a comparator for your own class and use that comparator.

Comment: `std::set` doesn't provide random access.

Comment: You need to provide more information about what you are trying to accomplish. It could be more efficient to just sort the content at the very end of your operation, depending on what you are trying to do. More information is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible : as you already noticed, the `std::set<>::find` member function expects a `const key_type &` (which, in a `std::set` is identical to `value_type`).

If you object is expensive to construct, chances are that you should better use a `std::map` (which also is a sorted container), possibly with values being (smart) pointers on your type.

Answer (score 3):

you can:

1) create a special "lightweigt" initializer for your class to create "ligtweight" version of your object and use such "lightweight" objects only as keys to access the map

2) use a map instead of a set.

I'd prefer the second solution.

Answer (score 2):

Set doesn't support random access iterator. If you want other way to compare objects(won't use operator <) you must do following

1)first way

```
bool compareFunciton(const setElementClass& lhs,const setElementClass& rhs)
{
    //return true if lhs's key is smaller than rhs and false at other case
}


set<setElementClass,compareFunction>  someSet;
```

2)Or you can use function-class instead of function like this

```
class compareClass
{
public:
    bool opreator()const setElementClass& lhs,const setElementClass& rhs)
   {
          //return true if lhs's key is smaller than rhs and false at other case
    }
};

compaerClass comp;
set<setElementClass,comp>  someSet;
```

Also I think you must look at functional header. There you can find some function-classes which you can use in the feauture. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use a set?

You might be better off using a map and generating a key (maybe a numerical index or a string) for your complex class, and then using the objects of the complex class as a value.

Just make sure your key follows the same ordering rules as the value. std::map is implemented as a tree, so it will also keep the items sorted according to the keys.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to define a less struct like this:

```
#include <set>

using std::binary_function;
using std::set;


struct very_complex
{
    int x, y;
};

struct less : public binary_function<very_complex, very_complex, bool>
{
    bool operator() (very_complex const& lho, very_complex const& rho)
    {
        if (lho.x != rho.x)
            return lho.x < rho.x;
        return lho.y < rho.y;
    }
}
```